# React-native: Scale image evenly, overlay text

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to learn to use react-native, and some even quite simple tasks seem to be extraordinarily complicated. For example, scaling an image evenly to a given percentage of the screen width (or, perhaps more precisely, of the width of the parent node). I can't find a simple way of doing this, that would work in all situations.

If I'm creating a View with flexDirection:'row', I discovered that I can add an image that's scaled to eg. 15% of the View's width by using the styles { width:'15%', resizeMode:'contain', aspectRatio:1 }.

However, if I'm adding the image to a View with flexDirection:'column', the above doesn't work (essentially, the width style has no effect). I couldn't figure out any other way of doing it than to add a sub-View that has flexDirection:'row', and contains an image with those styles. This seems to be an extraordinarily contrived way of doing it, and I might be missing something. One would think that there ought to be some kind of "scale" property to components, but I can't find any such thing.

Now the actual problem I'm having is that now I need to overlay some text on top of such an image. An Image cannot contain child nodes anymore, and the recommended way is to use ImageBackground.

The problem is that ImageBackground does not behave like Image in this situation. If I use the same styles as above, it does something strange: It seems to create a view with the correct width, eg. 15% or the parent's width, but then it crops the image itself from the left and the right so that only 15% of the center column is left (and left-aligns it in this view). So it kind of does scaling-down-to-15% twice: Once to create the view, and another to crop the image from the sides to another 15%. (The fact that it's doing exactly this can be corroborated by trying different percentages.)

All this seems extraordinarily complicated and contrived for something that's just a couple of one-liners in almost any graphical engine. How exactly is this supposed to be done?

All tutorials and answers to people's questions out there only talk about scaling images to some defined point size (like 150x150), not to a percentage of the screen width or height (which would be much more useful given that screen sizes and resolutions can vary a lot).